# How to store input value in javascript local storage in the form of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, set, local-storage

I am trying to store book name value in local storage when the form is submitted in the form of an array.
But bookName variable works, but it changes every time a new book name is entered as the function runs again.

```
let bookName = document.getElementById("bookName").value;
```

So i want to store all the book names in the form of an array and i get the following error. Here is code:

```
let libraryForm = document.getElementById("bookForm");
libraryForm.addEventListener("submit", libraryBooksDetails);

function libraryBooksDetails(e) {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("The book details have been submitted");
    let bookName = document.getElementById("bookName").value;
    let bookAuthor = document.getElementById("author").value;
    let bookType;
    let fiction = document.getElementById("Fiction"); 
    let programming = document.getElementById("ComputerProgramming");
    let personal = document.getElementById("PersonalDevelopement");
    
    if(fiction.checked){
        bookType = fiction.value;
    }
    else if(programming.checked){
        bookType = programming.value;
    }
    else if(personal.checked){
        bookType = personal.value;
    }

    let book = new bookDetails(bookName,bookAuthor,bookType);
    
    let bookData;
    bookData = bookData || [];
    let nameOfBooks = bookData.push(book.bookName);
    localStorage.setItem("books",JSON.stringify(nameOfBooks))
    console.log(book);

    let display = new Display()
    display.add(book);
    display.clear();
}
```

The function I used to store value returns 1. Don't know why?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that you're using the return value of `push`, which is the new length of the array (a number), not the array. If you want to store `bookData`, use that with `JSON.stringify`, not the `push` return value. More about storing JSON in local storage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162005/how-will-i-use-localstorage-with-object).

Comment: Thanks. I will read about it
The purpose is I want to store bookName value in local storage but every time a new bookName is entered the previously stored one gets changed.
So I am figuring on how to store all the books in the form of an array.
Any help would be really appreciated.